# I am using SOQL for accessing the data of salesforce using java

Tags: java, salesforce, soql

```
String uri = baseUri + "/query?q=Select+Id+from+Account+where+Id=+ ('017F00000nqmNPQAY')";
```

I am using SOQL for querying the data, it is working fine without where clause, but I don't know how to write it with where clause, It is throwing error when I am trying the above syntax. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Is that the intended way to query data?

Comment: Yes, without where clause i am getting the response, but with where clause it is not working.

Comment: I meant is there not a better API than to create an URL like that?

Comment: You need to escape the ``=`` in the query. Also I would highly recommend not to allow to pass in a whole query. Imagine ``/query?q=Delete+From+Account+where+1``.

Comment: Also: ``It is throwing error`` is not a problem description.

Comment: Can you suggest me some other way to write the same query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not do something like this:

```
URIBuilder ubuilder = new URIBuilder(baseUri);
ubuilder.setPath("/services/data/v39.0/query/")
   .setParameter("q", "SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id = '017F00000nqmNPQAY'");
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(ubuilder.build());
```